# Java: What data structure to use with predictable ordering, no duplicates and maintains it's own integer index?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I need to maintain column names, and not allow duplicate entries, while maintaining the order of these column names with associated index of it's own.

Down the road I need to swap column name at an index, and also add more column names to the end or beginning.

`LinkedHashSet<E>` seems like an ideal candidate, are there any others?

Need to support Synchronization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) has `SetUniqueList` - it is a `List` that guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: mappings between what? It's not a `Map`, so no. But I don't think the OP looks for a map (`Set` being his current preference)